# Gcloud cannot detect network connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gsutil

I have internet connection on the ESXi server and I want to copy everything to GCP storage. But Gcloud couldn't authenticate. It looks like it can't reach the gloud login servers.

I'm not if the esxi provider has blocked GCP IP's but is there a way I can verify? Do we know which IP or DNS address it tries to connect?

Could this be a different issue? I tried disable ipv6 and was hoping it would work.

```
./gcloud init --skip-diagnostics

    ERROR: There was a problem with web authentication.
    ERROR: (gcloud.auth.login) Could not reach the login server. A potential cause of this could be because you are behind a proxy. Please set the environment variables HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY to the address of the proxy in the format "protocol://address:port" (without quotes) and try again.
    Example: HTTPS_PROXY=https://192.168.0.1:8080
```

Comment: Hello John, `gcloud` questions should be asked in StackOverflow, since you have already created a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66347755/gcloud-cannot-detect-network-connection), you can follow updates on that track.

Answer (score 1):

For the error text you share, the problem can be an expired SSL certificate, check that all your certificates are current.

You do not mention how are you connected to the GCP storage, maybe [this article](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7511998?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) can help you if you are using a connector of that type. You can read [here](https://support.google.com/datastudio/topic/7332552?hl=en&ref_topic=9281288) about other types of connectors to Google products.

If you need to copy to Google a large amount of information, you can read [here](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/migration-to-google-cloud-transferring-your-large-datasets) abut other options that could be useful for you.